# How can I get feedback to the UI on a long running process in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a large folder of photos (36Gb) that I want to rename, move and check for duplicates. I'm tackling the renaming and moving of the files first. I created something similar as a console app a while back which worked but provided no mechanism for giving feedback on progress to a UI, so this would just appear to hang for almost an hour before completing.

If I want to do this in MVC how can I utilise an api endpoint or controller action to fire a service and get a response every time a file is renamed and moved? I'd like to be able to count the number of files and then have the UI update with 2323 of 10000.

Comment: This is a difficult problem to solve with a web application for the simple reason that Web apps are more or less "stateless".  They exist for the lifetime of one web request.  Now, you want to do a whole bunch of stuff over a long period of time... which is far longer than a single web request.  This can be done, but it requires a lot of infrastructure to make it happen, and frankly it's just not worth it unless you're building some kind of system to do this commercially.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to do major changes in web app and you can run console app on server then there is a simple hack you can do.

console app can write status in a file. in web app read the file and display it in appropriate format. for constant updates, console app has to write current status frequently. using ajax you can update user at every x seconds.

you can use json format like below

```
{
    "Total_Files" : xxx
    "Processed_Files" : yyy
    "Last_Operations" : 
         [ 
             "File x is renamed",
             "File x is duplicate. deleted"
         ]//"x amount of last operation you want to display" 
}
```